# Remove "" from string or in SQL varchar

Tags: c#, sql

Is it even possible to return value of string without the " " ?

I have the following string: `Chb = "NOT";`

Now i either want to remove the **""** in **C#** or **SQL**.

so i want to have either `Chb = NOT` in C#
,or i want to remove the **' '** in SQL that i get in @Chb so that this:
`WHERE PAR @Chb IN ('1','2','3')`

isnt like this : `WHERE PAR 'NOT' IN ('1','2','3')`

but it is like this `WHERE PAR NOT IN ('1','2','3')`

Comment: FYI, `IN ('1,2,3')` checks not for "1" or "2" or "3", but for the single string "1,2,3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is the right approach for this.

If you want to execute a command in SQL which comes from a C# code, then i would do:

```
string exists = "select * from table where var in (1,2,3)";
string notExists = "select * from table where var NOT in (1,2,3)";

if (chb != "NOT")
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(exists, con);
   cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
else
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(notExists, con);
   cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: this would probably solve it but i now did it in sql in a different way , thanks anyways....If anyone wondered i did it like this : `WHERE (@Chb = 1 AND PAR IN ('1','2','3') OR @Chb = 0 AND PAR NOT IN ('1','2','3'))`